# bootstrap how to add/remove category just like opencart?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Recently, I working on a PHP project that comes with product and product category. Each product can assign to multiple categories.

Product name, quantity all these are quite easy to handle as they are input text box. But for category, its a bit complicated. So i use checkboxes to handle category selection. It works fine for inserting mysql as i simply use foreach loop to check which checkbox has clicked. To update/del by using array_diff to check the new selected checkbox or unselected.

Then I found out that opencart handle category in this way

**1 input box for user to key in category name with auto suggestion, when clicking on the suggested name, it will be added. so to remove it, just click on the minus sign button. Its simply and straight forward.**

[image]

So I am wondering is there a way to do something like that by using bootstrap design? OR is there some opensource for such function ?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "its quite troublesome to handle it"? What have you tried and what's not working?

Comment: @Mike I think i shouldn't say troublesome and I should say how to do something like opencart way just like the screenshot?  I believe no matter which method i use, insert/update/delete mysql parts are the same.

Comment: That's not really on topic for this site then. This is for specific programming problems with your code, not recommending off-site resources or tutorials.

Comment: You can use "bootstrap tags input" plugin. Design is slightly different than what you posted though.
http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Other way would be to combine normal autocomplete with something like knockoutjs for modeling the addition/removal.